# What kind of measurement nontrivially preserves entropy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy

Majorization tells us that: 
*given the states $\rho$ and $\sigma$ of the same dimensions, if $\rho \prec \sigma$ then $S(\rho) \geq S(\sigma)$, where $S(\rho) = - \textrm{Tr} \rho \log \rho$ is the von Neumann entropy.* 
The equality indicates that the von Neumann entropy can be equivalent for two states admitting different spectrums.

We also know from a corollary of Horn's lemma that: 
*for a density matrix $\rho$, there exists an orthonormal basis $\{| \xi_k \rangle \}$ such that a measurement in this basis yields probabilities $p(k)$ iff $(p(k)) \prec λ(ρ)$, where $λ(ρ)$ and $(p(k))$ are the spectra of $\rho$ before and after measurement.*
([see Nielsen's unpublished book theorem 1.3.1](http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/talks/2002/maj/book.ps))

Hence for the chosen scenario where $\rho' \prec \rho$ and $S(\rho') = S(\rho)$ there should exist a measurement in an orthonormal basis $\{| \xi_k \rangle \}$ that creates $\rho'$ from $\rho$, that is, 
$$
\rho' = \sum_k | \xi_k \rangle \langle \xi_k | \rho | \xi_k \rangle \langle \xi_k | .
$$
**Question:** what criterion does $\{ \xi_i \}$ have to satisfy?

It can be easily visualized that for the qubit case such $\{ \xi_i \}$ only exists trivially for $\rho' = \rho$, since no matter what axis you project a Bloch vector to, it always decreases in length that is to increase in entropy, unless one project it to its own axis. But what about higher dimensions?

**ps:** In a previous question ([Linear purity and von Neumann entropy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363545/159580)) it was talked about how a single value of entropy may correspond to many different density matrices. However these matrices can be of majorizing order. This means if we characterize mixedness in two ways, one by von Neumann entropy the other by majorization, then the latter may be "degenerate" with respect to the former. For $\rho'$ and $\rho$ bearing the same entropy $S(\rho') = S(\rho)$, if one majorizes the other $\rho' \prec \rho$, i.e. $\rho'$ is more disordered than $\rho$, then a measurement in basis $\{| \xi_k \rangle \}$ (which is proven to exist in the first link) can take $\rho$ to $\rho'$. This is in part how my question arises.

Comment: How do you infer the specific form you give?  I'd be surprised if this works. This is not stated by said corollary.  --  Except for that, this is pretty much what is done in entanglement conversion, so I'm tempted to classify this as "homework".  --  Finally: What on earth has entropy to do with this?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch This is just some question I thought up while reading Nielsen's unpublished book, the link of which I've added. Entropy relates to this as in measurements usually increases entropy making the system more mixed, but now I find it possible that measurement can possibly preserve it. This can maybe mean it's not a good way to describe mixedness?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence with "Hence for the chosen scenario where $\rho' \prec \rho$ and $S(\rho) = S(\sigma)$". What is $\sigma$ here?

Comment: @Noiralef The $\sigma$ is supposed to be $\rho'$, it was a low end error on my part, I'm so sorry. By the way I've already proven for $S(\rho')=S(\rho)$, $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are incomparable, so nobody majorizes nobody, the measurement doesn't exist.

Comment: @L.Quen This really the same as the question when two states can be converted into each other by LOCC, which is given by majorization.  This should be answered in Nielsen's book.  (There is also a review by Nielsen which discusses this.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch OK, it seems like majorization is a fundamental concept for quantum correlations, I'll be sure to look into it.

Comment: Guess what ... that's why Nielsen drafted a whole book on it ;-)