# Generalised basis independent relationship between Von Neumann Entropy and Purity of a quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density

I have been trying to find a generalized relationship between Von Neumann Entropy and Purity of a quantum state? [In this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363545/) there is a discussion of a specific case for a qubit and a more general case of a multi-level system but, I believe these are relations for the system in a given state basis. Is there a to work this out some way in which we can keep this in a basis-independent formalism.

Comment: in the linked post they show that there is no one-to-one relation between the two quantities. What do you mean that "the relations  are basis-dependent"?

Comment: Duplicate of  [What is the relation between linear purity and von Neumann entropy of a state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/363545/what-is-the-relation-between-linear-purity-and-von-neumann-entropy-of-a-state)

Comment: Entropies are *not* basis dependent.  --  Also, you need to make it very clear what the difference to the linked question is.