# Is Purity monotonically decreasing with increasing Von Neumann entropy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I want to know whether Purity is monotonically decreasing for increasing Von Neumann entropy or not.

In other words, I want to know whether the following proposition holds or not,
\begin{align}
S(\rho_1)<S(\rho_2)~~~~\Longleftrightarrow ~~~~
\text{Tr}\rho_1^2>\text{Tr}\rho_2^2,
\end{align}
where $S(\rho)=-\text{Tr}\rho\log \rho$ is the Von Neumann entropy.

Comment: How many examples did you check?

Comment: I checked the monotonically decreasing in a 2-dimensional qubit case, which was argued in the previous question. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/363545/what-is-the-relation-between-linear-purity-and-von-neumann-entropy-of-a-state

Comment: Why have you not explored the 3d parametric plots discussed in that linked question?

Comment: Qubits are not enough.  In the case of qubits, the mixedness is parametrized by a single parameter. Check a qutrit!

Comment: Note that the linked question + answers *does* make it clear that you should go beyond qubits!  Also, strict equivalent monotonicity *will* imply a 1-to-1 relation (i.e. one can be computed from the other), since then for each value of one there can only be *one* value for the other quantity.  So essentially this is a duplicate of said question, asking whether there is a unique relation between the two quantities.  No, there isn't.

Comment: Thank you for your replies and I understand the proposition does not hold from the linked question because there is no one-to-one correspondence between them.
So I am going to withdraw this question.
Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: It would be best if you would mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate. Thank you for your advice.